# IIS error getting userdata from AD

Tags: c#, .net, iis, active-directory

My code which gets user data from AD works in console app or when I run project in Visual Studio but when I deploy it to IIS code doesn't work.

**CODE**

```
public static User GetUserByName(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return null;
    }

    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> users = null;

    User result = null;

    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, name);

        result = FillUser(user);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**ERROR**

> 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090724, comment: In order to perform this
>   operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data
>   0, v23f0

in line

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, name);
```

Why?

Comment: Hard to say without specified values, but check the address and port number expecially. Do you use LDAP port? And have you enabled the Windows authentication on IIS? A valid certificate?...

Comment: Port and adress are defults, no changes. Yes Windows authentication is enabled, others disabled.

Comment: What is the identity of the app pool assigned to the web site? Some of the defaults will not work and you may need to change the account on the app pool to a domain account with the appropriate permissions

Comment: @MikeBeeler identity is default ApplicationPoolIdentity, but when I change identity to my domain account nothing change, still errror.